# azure push notification send with a button

Tags: azure, xamarin

I am trying to send a push notification with a button in azure notification hub. I just found this example for iOS,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-apple-push-notification-service-apns-rich

Is there a way to add a button to azure push notifications to Xamarin forms

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

The documentation of how to do this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms

Edit:

To get a cancel button you need to define a dismiss action:

```
var categoryID = "message";
var actions = new UNNotificationAction [] { action };
var intentIDs = new string [] { };
var categoryOptions = new UNNotificationCategoryOptions [] { };
var category = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier (categoryID, actions, intentIDs, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.CustomDismissAction);
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows

Comment: Thanks But I did this already. I need to send a button with the push notification. As example : If I sent a App Update message Push notification should be with Update button and cancel button.